# render very high quality text to bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, render

I want to put some text on an image. Here is my method:

```cs
private Bitmap ConvertTextToImage(string text, FontFamily fontFamily, float fontSize, FontStyle fontStyle = FontStyle.Regular,
    StringFormat stringFormat = default, float MaxWidth = float.MaxValue, float MaxHeight = float.MaxValue, Color backgroundColor = default, Color foregroundColor = default)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
    if (stringFormat == default) stringFormat = new StringFormat();
    if (backgroundColor == default) backgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
    if (foregroundColor == default) foregroundColor = Color.Black;

    Font font = new Font(fontFamily, fontSize, fontStyle);

    SizeF stringSize = graphics.MeasureString(text, font, int.MaxValue, stringFormat);
    while (stringSize.Width > MaxWidth || stringSize.Height > MaxHeight)
    {
        fontSize -= (float)0.1;
        font = new Font(fontFamily, fontSize, fontStyle);
        stringSize = graphics.MeasureString(text, font, int.MaxValue, stringFormat);
    }
    
    bitmap = new Bitmap((int)stringSize.Width, (int)stringSize.Height);
    graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
    graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
    graphics.Clear(backgroundColor);
    
    int x = 0;
    if (stringFormat.FormatFlags == StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft && stringFormat.Alignment == StringAlignment.Center)
        x = (int)stringSize.Width / 2;
    else if (stringFormat.FormatFlags == StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft) x = (int)stringSize.Width;
    else if (stringFormat.Alignment == StringAlignment.Center) x += (int)stringSize.Width / 2;
    
    graphics.DrawString(text, font, new SolidBrush(foregroundColor), x, 0, stringFormat);
    return bitmap;
}
//...
```

Good for big font sizes or simple fonts (eg. Samim). But for a complex font (IranNastaliq) in small size, it gets like this (brown is on main image and black is generated by C#):
[image]
So I decided to use `GraphicsPath.AddString` instead of `Graphics.DrawString`:

```cs
GraphicsPath graphicsPath = new GraphicsPath();
//...
graphicsPath.AddString(text, fontFamily, (int)fontStyle, fontSize * graphics.DpiY / 72, new Point(x, 0), stringFormat);
graphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(foregroundColor), graphicsPath);
```

But result is still bad:
[image]
How can I render higher quality texts? Image resolution is 2480x3508x300dpi and font size is about 13.

Comment: You need high resolution fonts. See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-use-antialiasing-with-text

Comment: Do all fonts incl. Windows standard fonts look the same? - Also: Do set the dpi of the bitmap to take full control..!

Comment: @jdweng As you can see in my code, I used antialiasing. But still not acceptable.

Comment: What about "SingleBitPerPixel"?

Comment: @jdweng It makes it even worse.

Comment: @TaW I set DPI to 300x300 and it worked. Please send your solution as an answer so I can mark it as accepted solution.

Comment: Glad to hear. I don't post answers here any longer, though, sorry. You may want to self-answer the question. Include the new code and also a screenshot of the result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to TaW's comment, problem solved. I should adjust bitmap resolution (DPI) to match resolution of original picture. Here is correct code:

```cs
private Bitmap ConvertTextToImage(string text, FontFamily fontFamily, float fontSize,
    FontStyle fontStyle = FontStyle.Regular, StringFormat stringFormat = default,
    float MaxWidth = float.MaxValue, float MaxHeight = float.MaxValue, float xDpi = 72, float yDpi = 72,
    Color backgroundColor = default, Color foregroundColor = default)
{
    //...
    graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
    bitmap.SetResolution(xDpi,yDpi);
    //...
    graphics.DrawString(text, font, new SolidBrush(foregroundColor), x, 0, stringFormat);
}

private void Write()
{
    //...
    Bitmap name = ConvertTextToImage(Name.Text, IranNastaliq, 58, MaxWidth: 525, xDpi: 300, yDpi: 300);
    graphics.DrawImage(name, new Point(1104, 1700));
    //...
    bitmap.Save("img.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Result (black text is drawn by GDI):
[image]